# Why are terabytes of memory suddenly requested?

Tags: 9

A couple of days ago I configured my server to use PHP-FPM to use different versions of PHP for different sites. After that they worked fine. Two Drupal 9 sites are using PHP 8.1, other Drupal 7 sites are using PHP 7.4.

Without any changes I am aware of, the sites stopped working. The server log file contains a warning regarding memory usage:

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted
> (tried to allocate 7002662505284858752 bytes) in Unknown on line 0

I had already raised the memory_limit from 512mb to 1gb. Before, the error message reflected the other setting:

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted
> (tried to allocate 7002662505284858752 bytes) in Unknown on line 0

I even tried to set it to -1:

> PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 2097152) (tried to allocate
> 7002662505284858752 bytes) in Unknown on line 0

How on earth could Drupal suddenly use 7.002.662.505.284.858.752 bytes of memory? That's 7.002.662.505 gb or 7.002.662 tb.

At the same time I got errors regarding SSL certificates. All sites use certificates from Let's Encrypt and worked without a problem. Running checks on https://www.ssllabs.com, no problem appears. I configured the sites to run without https, but the memory error remains.

I can't even log into my sites, but using Drush, the watchdog log doesn't show anything important.

On some pages or sites, using Chrome, I get the error ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

I am kind of lost after some hours of searching. Does anybody have an idea what could be causing this?

**Update:**
I created an issue on drupal.org: [Auto-generated .htaccess in files directory breaks sites](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3346348)

Comment: If you did not change the Drupal codebase around the time this began you should inquire to your hosting company or sysadmins about any changes they made around that time.

Comment: Thanks cilefen. The sites are running on a server that I manage. So I pretty much know what I did.. The only thing I can relate to this is that I raised the PHP memory_limit yesterday.

Comment: Does any PHP script execute?

Comment: Currently the Drupal sites are loading more or less, but with errors when js and images are loaded. When I turn CSS and JS aggregation on, all layouts disappear. But generally, the sites work. When I try to open an image or JS file in sites/default/files directly, I get an SSL error in Firefox (in Chrome: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)

Comment: What we usually do is, if there is a bug report, is to close the Question here. But I don't in fact think you have uncovered a bug in Drupal but rather some kind of issue with that platform setup. Drupal isn't even serving the files in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

I investigated a lot and it seems the problem was that after installing PHP-FPM, I didn't disable mod_php. Now I ran

```
sudo a2dismod php7.4
```

and rebuilt all caches. The error does not appear anymore, at least by now.

Before, I found that this part in `sites/default/files/.htaccess` of Drupal 8 and 9 sites caused SSL errors that lead to the problems described above:

```
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
  php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php.c>
  php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
```

Commenting them out (adding # in every line) made the sites work properly and apparently also makes the memory error disappear. After disabeling mod_php, the sites ran with the original `.htaccess` created by Drupal.

#### Maintaining security features with PHP-FPM

In my understanding, using PHP-FPM means that the security features in `.htaccess` won't work. One workaround I found was adding this before `<IfModule mod_php7.c>` in `sites/default/files/.htaccess`:

```
<Files "*.php">
  SetHandler none
  SetHandler default-handler
  Options -ExecCGI
  RemoveHandler .php
</Files>
```

This will lead to security warnings by the Security Review in Drupal, though, because the `.htaccess` file has been altered. Another way is to change the configuration directly in the Apache conf file as decribed [here](https://xdeb.org/post/2017/running-drupal-on-debian-9-with-apache-2-4-http2-event-mpm-and-php-fpm-via-socks-and-proxy/) (I adapted it a little):

```
# Security setting for files folder in Drupal.
<DirectoryMatch "^/var/www/.*/sites/.*/(files|tmp)">
    # Turn off all options we don't need.
    Options -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes -MultiViews

    # Set the catch-all handler to prevent scripts from being executed.
    SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
    <Files *>
        # Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
        SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
    </Files>

    # If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
    <IfModule mod_php7.c>
        php_flag engine off
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_php.c>
        php_flag engine off
    </IfModule>
</DirectoryMatch>

# Security setting for config folder in Drupal.
<DirectoryMatch "^/var/www/.*/sites/.*/(private|config|sync|translations|twig)">
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>

    # Deny all requests from Apache 2.0-2.2.
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
    # Turn off all options we don't need.
    Options -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes -MultiViews

    # Set the catch-all handler to prevent scripts from being executed.
    SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
    <Files *>
        # Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
        SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
    </Files>

    # If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
    <IfModule mod_php7.c>
        php_flag engine off
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_php.c>
        php_flag engine off
    </IfModule>
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Comment: I just created a new D10 site, and that line is already uncommented. Did someone comment it out? Is it possible there is a hacker trying to get executable php files into your site?

Comment: I might have misspoken: Default state is that those lines are active (which causes my errors). When I comment them out (adding # in every line), the errors disappear. Of course that makes my sites less secure. But it was me who commented them out.

Comment: You should probably update the issue on d.org and change "uncomment" to "comment" for clarity too

Comment: Thanks Clive, I corrected both here and on drupal.org.